# Call a file with scripts and css references

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

Not sure if the title makes sense, but I'm trying to determine with an ASP.net web project master page if there is a way to reference a file that contains the css and js references like would normally appear in the head section of a master page. As an example my project will have multiple master pages, rather than repeat a reference to say bootstrap.min.js 3 times I'd like to have it in a separate file with the other references that I can then call from the master page. Almost like having a master page over the others. Searched around google quite a bit but non of the searches were resulting in a direction I could use.

Comment: Create `bundles` and use them.

Comment: Thanks that got me in the right direction. Since it's a web project I added directly to the application_start in global.asax.

Answer (score 0):

Within the Application_Start sub in the Global.asax page I added the following code:

```
        Dim jsBndl As ScriptBundle = New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/js")
    jsBndl.Include(New String() {"~/Scripts/validation.js",
                       "~/Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.min.js",
                       "~/Scripts/popper.min.js",
                       "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
                       "~/Scripts/tinymce/tinymce.min.js",
                       "~/Scripts/bootstrap-toggle.min.js",
                       "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
                       "~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.min_.js"})

    Dim cssBndl As StyleBundle = New StyleBundle("~/bundles/css")
    cssBndl.Include(New String() {"~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
                                 "~/Content/dashboard.css",
                                 "~/Content/site.css",
                                 "~/Content/animate.css",
                                 "~/Content/pagination.css",
                                 "~/Content/bootstrap-toggle.min.css",
                                 "~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.css"})

    BundleTable.Bundles.Add(jsBndl)
    BundleTable.Bundles.Add(cssBndl)
```

Then in the master page I just added:

```
<%= System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/js") %>    
<%= System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/bundles/css") %>
```

You'll need to make sure that you get the web optimization package from nuget as well.